# Covenant level ups from npc invaders

Tags: dark-souls-2

In Dark Souls 2, there are several ways to level up PvP covenants without actually going online. For example you can level up the Covenant of Champions by farming the invader in Grave of Saints by burning Ascetics to make him respawn, essentially giving you infinite awe stones.

Another method for the Bell Covenant is to farm the Mad Warrior in Belfry Sol. So I was wondering if you could do this for other covenants as well? Eg. For the Rat Covenant or Blue Sentinels.

Comment: In regards to the Rat King Covenant, while not npc invaders, I believe the small rats found near the two optional bosses have a chance to drop Rat Tails used to advance relations. As well as the two Rat Tails you get from the Royal Rat Authority and Royal Rat Vanguard optional bosses, this is all I can think of off the top of my head.

Comment: Yeap its a Rare drop from rats.

Comment: do you mean all Covenants "offline"? or just the once with PvP ?

Comment: @GEnGEr Well any really. If I can level up Covenants like BoB or Blue Sentinels without having to wade through hours of PvP that would be amazing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heirs of the Sun (sunBro): needs Sunlight Medal -> drop from Falconer Knights and Banediggers
Pilgrims of Dark: is already in "offline mode"

Brotherhood of Blood: needs to be done in Dual arena online

Company of Champions: like you sad needs Awe stone -> rare drop from a few Mobs see [Wiki](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Awestone)

Blue Sentinel: also done in the duals arena online

Way of Blue: ranking gained from fighting invaders, both PC and NPC

Bell Keepers: can be levelled up from fighting the Mad Worrior

Rat King: needs Rat Tails -> rare drop from rats

Dragon Remnants: needs Dragon Scales -> rare drop from Dragon Soldiers

Comment: I believe the "Dark magic giants" you're referring too are called "Banedigger"